# Roots of cubic equation -. Special type

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, cubics

Can we find the roots of a cubic equation given that Thier sum is zero. Q-. $4x^3 - 3x + 1/2 =0$.  I tried eliminating $3$ equation $3$ variables but ending up again with the same cubic in terms of beta.

Comment: Substitute $x \leftarrow \cos(y)$ and you get $\cos(3y) + \tfrac12 = 0$.

Comment: I have got up to this equation just to find out the value of cos(40) without using calculator. Want to solve algebraically and find out value of cos(40).

Comment: Since the roots of this eqution are some, I would call them not so nice, numbers (to be exact $x_1=0.766044443119,x_2=0.173648177667,x_3=-0.939692620786$) I would suggest Newton's method for example to compute the roots.

Comment: See WP on [Casus Irreducibilis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis). Using the formula for solutions of a cubic equation in general necessitates the use of complex cubic roots. Meaning that the zeros, here $\cos(2^k\pi/9)$, $k=0,1,2$, simply cannot be written in terms of real valued radicals and such. Either complex cubic roots or trig functions (here involving angle trisection, so circular in a sense) are needed. Make your pick!

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $$x \leftarrow \frac12 (y + \frac1y)$$
to get $$\frac{y^6+y^3+1}{2y^3}.$$
Then solve this as a quadratic equation in $y^3$.

Comment: It doesn't seem appropriate to me! Solving that equation would lead us to $y^3 + \frac{1}{y^3} = -1$ ,which is not possible!

Comment: Yes you are right Creep sir

Comment: The algebraic solution (with radicals) involves the expression $\sqrt[3]{-\frac12 + \tfrac12\sqrt{-3}}$. Which was to be expected from the trigonometric solution.